# Using gsub on a dataframe from one column applied to another column

Tags: r

If I have a simple data from that looks like this:

```
    Position    Change
    76          A->B
    43          C->D
```

How can I create a combined column that inserts the position between the change, removing the arrow ('->'). For instance

```
    Position  Change  Combined
    76        A->B     'A76B'
    43        C>D      'C43D'
```

I tried using gsub like this:

```
df$Combined<-gsub("->",df$Position, df$Change)
```

but only a zero gets inserted, not the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Richard Scriven said, `gsub` is not vectorized over `replacement` or `x`, but in base R you can create a vectorized version:

```
gsub_v <- Vectorize(gsub, c("replacement", "x"))
gsub_v("->", df$Position, df$Change)
```

Answer (score 3):

`gsub()` is not vectorized over `replacement`, but there is a function in the *stringi* package that is, and it is very efficient. We can use `stri_replace_all_fixed()` since we have a fixed string we want to replace.  Using a fixed string makes the operation more efficient.

```
with(df, stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(Change, "->", Position))
# [1] "A76B" "C43D"
```

There is a similar function in the *stringr* package as well.  Here we can wrap the string to be replaced with `fixed()` to denote that we are looking for a fixed string.  This package wraps *stringi* (in a sense) and is also very efficient.

```
with(df, str_replace_all(Change, fixed("->"), Position))
# [1] "A76B" "C43D"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
df$com<-with(df,gsub('->',Position,Change))
Position Change  com
1       76   A->B A76B
2       43   C->D C76D
```